# Getting null while parsing JSON using Jackson

Tags: java, json, parsing, null, jackson

I am trying to parse a JSON using Jackson,here is my class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Customer {
    private String name;
    
    public void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

and the runner class

```
public class jsontoObj {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String json = "{\n" +
                    "  \"customer\":\n" +
                    "  {\n" +
                    "    \"name\": \"John Doeyy\"\n" +
                    "  }\n" +
                    "}";

            Customer customer = mapper.readValue( json, Customer.class);
            System.out.println(customer.getName());
    }

}
```

the `setName` method is working but getting `null` in `customer.getName()`.
I don't want to use moxy

Comment: You have an object within an object. The internal object matches your `Customer` but you are trying to parse the *external* object, which only has a `customer` attribute, not a `name` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

A correct json according to your mapping would be

`String json = "{ \"name\": \"John Doeyy\" }";`

I removed the embeded "customer" object